# javascript inheritance with prototype - redundant object

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a tutorial about inheritance in JavaScript, and there is the following statement:

For an object of Rabbit class to inherit from Animal class we need:

1. Define Animal
2. Define Rabbit
3. Inherit Rabbit from Animal:

   Rabbit.prototype = new Animal()

They say that this approach has a disadvantage of a need to create a redundant object. I don't understand why I need to create that redundant object? I've tried the following and it worked without creating redundant objects:

```
function Animal() {};
function Rabbit() {};
Rabbit.prototype = Animal.prototype
Animal.prototype.go = function() {alert("I'm inherited method"};
var r = new Rabbit();
r.go();
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is that with your code, `Rabbit` and `Animal` share the *exact same* prototype.  If you added an `eatCarrot` method to `Rabbit` then every other `Animal` would have that method too.

The tutorial you're using is actually somewhat out of date.  The preferred way to subclass instead is to use `Object.create` to create a brand new `prototype` object for Rabbit that chains to the `Animal.prototype`:

```
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;
```

Note that this does *not* depend on subclassing the `Rabbit` from an *instance* of `Animal`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

There is a critical deficiency of your approach, best demonstrated by an example:

```
function Animal() {};
Animal.prototype.feed = function(){
  console.log("feeding")
};

function Rabbit() {this.teeth = 4};
Rabbit.prototype = Animal.prototype; // oops
Rabbit.prototype.feed = function(){
  if(this.teeth > 1){
    console.log("chewing")
  } else {
    throw "I have no teeth!"
  }
}

var leechworm = new Animal;
leechworm.feed(); //throws
```

since `leechworm` is an `Animal`, it should be able to feed no matter what kinds of animals we define, but since `Animal.prototype === Rabbit.prototype`, `Animal.prototype.feed` is the same as `Rabbit.prototype.feed`. The leechworm will complain about his lack of teeth.